# localhost:8545 400 bad request

Tags: localhost, blockchain, solidity

I study solidity in my localhost 
I run ganache-cli
and i can see

`...
...`

## Gas Price

20000000000

## Gas Limit

6721975

Listening on 127.0.0.1:8545

but http://localhost:8545/ 
400 Bad Request

web3.js:4348 Failed to load http://localhost:8545/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: You should look in to other topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081412/signalr-angular-failed-to-loadurl-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass#52082198)

Comment: You don't really send the request yourself sou cannot add headers to it.There is a discussion about this on web3.js issues page. You can find it here: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1802